# How to intersect Box3Ds with PostGIS 2.3?

Tags: postgis, 3d, st-intersects

I am storing several axis aligned bounding box representing complex gemoetries as

```
BOX3D(POINTZ(x1,y1,z1), POINTZ(x2,y2,z2))
```

I need to perform queries to identify elements that intersects a given query BOX3D.

It seems that PostGIS allows using st_3Dintersects only with POINTZ, LINESTRING and TIN

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: It is supposed to work for polygons per the documentation, and you should be able to cast. I didn't actually try it though - so  another option if you are only doing axis-aligned, you could cast to 2D and use `ST_Intersects` plus a manual check of extents in the Z direction.

Comment: What version of PostGIS?

Comment: PostGIS 2.3 (question edited to add it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a box3d from a geometry collection with these two points (a linestring could be also valid):

```
Box3D('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z (POINT Z (x1 y1 z1),POINT Z (x2 y2 z2))'::geometry)

Box3D(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(x1 y1 z1, x2 y2 z2)'))
```

Then, you can use the `&&&` operator to check if two n-D float precision bounding boxes intersect each other.

[`&&&(gidx,gidx)`](http://postgis.net/docs/overlaps_nd_gidx_gidx.html)

```
SELECT a1 &&& a2 AS "isOverlaped", ST_3DIntersects(a1,a2)
FROM ( VALUES
  (
    box3d('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z (POINT Z (-10 -10 -10),POINT Z (10 10 10))'::geometry),
    box3d('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z (POINT Z (-5 -5 -5),POINT Z (5 5 5))'::geometry)
  )
) AS t(a1, a2);

 isOverlaped | st_3dintersects 
-------------+-----------------
 t           | t
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question: you're not explaining at all how `&&&` is the solution to the problem. `ST_3Dintersects` also returns true for that test.

Comment: In my answer, the operator &&& can handle Z components if you are working with BOX3D (I provide the link just for clarify and add documentation). Your proposal is returning true as well because ST_3DIntersects is considering a projection (only works with points, linestrings, polygons, polyhedral surface and TIN, [ST_3DIntersects](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_3DIntersects.html)) avoiding the box3d 3-dimensional aspect were asked.

Comment: I just don't get it he says "st_3Dintersects only with POINTZ, LINESTRING and TIN" that's clearly not true. Here it's working with box3d as they get converted to polygons and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try running this and pasting the output,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(bb), ST_AsText(geom), ST_3DIntersects(bb, geom)
FROM ( VALUES
  ( Box3D(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0 0, 5 5 5)')) )
) AS t(bb)
CROSS JOIN ( VALUES
  ( ST_MakePoint(0,0,-1) ),
  ( ST_MakePoint(0,0,0) ),
  ( ST_MakePoint(2,2,2) ),
  ( ST_MakePoint(7,7,7) ),
  ( ST_MakePoint(0,7,0) )
) AS points(geom);
```